# What's the difference between these conditionals? "I will call you if I have done/do my homework"

Tags: grammar, conditionals, present-perfect

What's the difference between using (1) a present perfect in the *if* part of a simple conditional, and (2) using just a regular present tense without a perfect there?

1. I will call you if I **have done** my homework.
2. I will call you if I **do** my homework.

Comment: Your title asks about semantics, your tags ask about syntax. How 'bout if I just give you a call once my homework's done? :)

Comment: Hey, I might have tagged it wrong. The thing is, I need to know the difference between those two options. :)

Comment: Tell us first what  you think the difference might be. Doesn't "have done" sound like the past?

Comment: Yes, the main difference I see is that the 1st option emphasizes the finished aspect of an action. Is that correct? Are there any other significant differences?

Comment: You are right because if I do is not finished, is it? :)

Comment: Yes, is there anything else to it?

Comment: @Martin When answering a request for details, please remember to [edit] your post to include your answer. Never trust that people will read the comments for clarifications. It's an important way to avoid having your questions closed.

Comment: You should indicate what you already know about this issue, including the research that you've done. People who volunteer their time on this site shouldn't be expected to do all of your work for you, and knowing what you already know will help them to provide more useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If I have done" means that the homework is finished.

"If I do" means that the homework has been started, but not necessarily completed.

- I'd like to join you guys tonight, but I've got a lot of homework to finish first, so I might not make it there.
  *I will call you if I have done my homework*, to let you know I'll be there.
- I've got a lot of homework for this weekend.
  Rather than hanging out with you, I might work on it tonight to get most of it out of the way, so I'll have more time for you tomorrow.
  *I will call you if I do my homework*, to let you know I won't be there.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is not very natural.

It depends on what you are trying to say. If you are trying to say that you might or might not do your homework, then you could say:

*"If I do my homework I will call you afterwards"*.

If you definitely intend to do your homework:

*"I will call you when I have done my homework"*

In your first construction the tenses don't really work together as it stands. Although you **could** say:

*"I will call you if I have done my homework by 9"*.